# What is hammering the CPU when top is not running?

Tags: cpu, top

On Kubuntu 12.10 I can see with the KDE System Monitor Plasmoid that the CPU usage is fluctuating between 60% - 90% on both cores. As soon as I open `top` it goes down to 3% - 10%. I thought that the issue is that I'm 'doing nothing' while looking at `top`, so I closed `top` (just pressed `q`) and still did nothing with the keyboard nor mouse. However the CPU usage jumps back up to where it was. What might be smart enough to calm down while `top` is running?

Answer (score 0):

If you do something while top is closed, like type slowly in kedit/gedit and the cpu usage goes down then this supports the theory that some on-idle process is running and running top is not counted as being idle.  While doing nothing while top is closed is counted as being idle, so the on-idle process roars to life.

What does the following command reveal?

```
sudo ps -efH
```

Comment: Thank you, [here is the output](http://pastebin.com/gLPJFtFf).

Comment: the number 1 cpu user on that list seems to be lightdm, try the suggestions on http://askubuntu.com/questions/163264/how-can-i-reduce-the-cpu-usage-of-x-lightdm

Comment: followed by /usr/bin/dolphin which seems to have troubles with video thumbnails search for "/usr/bin/dolphin cpu" without the quotes for info on that